# D3.js rect no display on chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, charts

I started the D3.js challenge on FreeCodeCamp, the problem is that I solved it with the chart but it only gives me a display on the rectum, only one with the width and height that it I put, I'll show the code below.

The entire code on

```
<script>

    //set d3
    var w = 1000, h  = 500;
    var padding = 50;
    var svg = d3.select('body')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', w)
                .attr('height', h)
    
    //title
    svg.append('text')
        .attr('x', w / 2)
        .attr('y', 50)
        .text('United States GDP')


    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json')
    .then((result)=>result.json())
    .then((data)=>{

        var the_data = data['data']

        //get vals
        var get_max = d3.max(data['data'])
        var get_mix = d3.min(data['data'])

        //for x
        var max_x = Number(get_max[0].split('-')[0])
        var min_x = Number(get_mix[0].split('-')[0])

        //for y
        var max_y = get_max[1]
        var min_y = get_mix[1]


        var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .domain([min_x, max_x])
                        .range([padding, w-padding])

        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .domain([min_y, max_y])
                        .range([h-padding, padding])


        //the_chars
        for(var i in the_data){
            var get_year = Number(the_data[i][0].split('-')[0])
            the_data[i][0] = get_year
        }

        svg.selectAll('rect')
            .data(the_data)
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr("x", (d) => { xScale(d[0]) })
            .attr('y', (d)=>{ yScale(d[1]) })
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", 20)

        //axis
        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

        //display axis
        svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

        svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding + ', 0)')
        .call(yAxis)




    })
```

Now, what I need to do to display the charts!

I mention that the script tags are embedded in the body

Comment: the for change data year string to int, and the arrays will be [int, int], I console log to see if works, and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Problem**: Arrow functions without a return value. **Solution**: Instead use an explicit or an implicit return.

```
.attr("x", (d) => { xScale(d[0]) }) // returns undefined
.attr("x", (d) => xScale(d[0])) // implicit return
.attr("x", (d) => { return xScale(d[0]) }) // explicit return
```

2. **Problem**: Fixed height value. **Solution** Evaluate the height of each  based on the GDP value (`d[1]`) instead.

```
.attr('height', 20) // fixed height
.attr('height', d => yScale(min_y) - yScale(d[1]))
// subtract from min range to account for padding and inverted y coordinates in SVG
```

Full solution in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/shreshthmohan/pen/ZEvYNNv)

[image: Solution screenshot]